# From the thousands of the overlaid polygons, get clusters of density

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a few thousands of the polygons, over the given region. Many of them overlay. What I want is to detect areas, where density (number of overlaying polygons at the point) is substantially higher than around.

My first attempt is to create a grid of points and for each point count the number of polygons that it intersects. From that, I can get an overall heat map and spot the areas of the highest density.

However, as density varies a lot, I imagine some minor (local) spots remain hidden, as total numbers are not that hight. So I am looking for a technique that will allow me to detect spatially segregated clusters that have the density that is way higher than their surrounding.

It sounds like a contour detection in CV, so I really hope to find the code for the problem